# How to execute Linq queries in Serenity

Tags: linq

I have created an application using Serenity framework. I have completed basic functionality for CRUD using serenity. Based on my tables I need to have graphical representations, any charts like high charts, D3 charts or any . 
1. How can I get data from the tables using Linq in serenity

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the answer for this. We can use sql queries as well as stored procedure to fetch data from DB. I have used stored procedure and linq to get the data from db.

In repository page you can add Linq,

```
public ListResponse<MyRow> GetUsers(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        // This must be te Repository
        var myRepos = new UserRepository();
        // This must be a type of Request (in this case ListRequest)
        var request = new ListRequest();
        request.Take = 100;
        // This must be a type of Response (in this case ListResponse)
        var response = new ListResponse<MyRow>();
        // This must be called on Repository
        var result = myRepos.List(connection, request);
        // Data 
        var data = result.Entities.Where(r => r.Name != "").ToList();
        response.Entities = data;
        return response;
    }
```

I have already defined MyRow as UserRow like this using MyRow = Entities.UserRow;.

Hope this will help you.